# Ruling on cutting hair short (women)

Tags: halal-haram, women, hair

Is it permissible to have hair cut short if there is a necessity? I suffer from excessive hair loss (a *lot*) and I had my hair cut short. I only did it for purpose of necessity, not for imitation (of kafirs) or beauty, is this haram?

Comment: Sister it all depends on your sincere intention. If it was advised by a health professional for your own good then you've got no issues.

Comment: Jazak Allah Khairan

Answer (score 1):

The views of scholars may vary depending on your religion and culture. What I searched for in the eyes of Shiite scholars is that most of them consider it is not forbidden to shave  woman's hair. Provided, of course, that the intention is not to resemble men.
But even scholars who do not consider it permissible to shave a woman's hair, if there is an excuse, they consider it permissible to shave a woman's hair for treatment.

Therefore, in the opinion of both groups, because you shaved your hair to treat and prevent more hair loss, you have not committed a sin.
But, dear sister, it is better to modify your diet to get better results in preventing and treating hair loss.

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.yjc.news/fa/amp/news/7603496&ved=2ahUKEwif1_2PoZf0AhVSQfEDHfb1BsUQFnoECBkQAQ&usg=AOvVaw025ZQVBS__5oOvjlsnWhp9&ampcf=1